# Make div top on top of another, without position and using only inline css

Tags: html, css, inline

I'm trying to design a letter to send from my website to customers, and I copied a simple design like so

https://jsfiddle.net/ju6twwtk/

I would like to cover the bottom-right corner, with the image of an angle, but I can't get this element:

```
<div style="float:right; padding-top:15px;">   
  <img src="http://s017.radikal.ru/i407/1605/de/a777fd1811b5.png">
</div>
```

to float on top of the border. Because I'm making a letter, I cannot really use css classes, so I need to use only inline-css. Also as you can see from jsfiddle, when you resize the window the bottom-right corner image starts to float in weird locations.

```
   <div style="font-size: 80%; margin: 15px 0; clear: both;">
    <div style="width: 100%; border-top: 1px dotted #d8d8d8;">
        <a title="" href="http://example.com">
            <div style="margin-left: 16px; margin-bottom: -16px; padding-top: 16px;">
                <div style="width:180px;height:120px; border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;">
                    <div style="position: relative; height: 85px; text-align: center;">
                        <div style="padding: 20px;">
                            <img style="width: 32px; height: 32px;" src="http://www.iconsplace.com/icons/preview/salmon/pig-256.png">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="height: 34px; top: 85px; width: 100%; right: 0; left: 0; background-color: #f5f5f5; border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;">
                        <div style="float:left; height: 34px; width: 35px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; line-height: 40px;">
                            <img style="width: 16px; height: 16px; border: none;" src="http://araskie.xtgem.com/file/images/16x16/Dollar.png" title="Currency">
                        </div>

                        <div style="float :left; font-size: 12px; color: #777; font-weight: bold; line-height: 1.2em; margin-top: 9px; margin-right: 30px; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap; word-wrap: normal;">
                            <span style="font-family: arial,sans-serif;">some text will go here</span>
                        </div>
                        <div style="float:right; padding-top:15px;">

                            <img src="http://s017.radikal.ru/i407/1605/de/a777fd1811b5.png">

                        </div>

                    </div>


                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
```

What would be the best strategy to make that corner stay in place and cover the border in the bottom-right corner? Also I cannot really use negative margins, because they got stripped by email services.

Comment: if you are making a newsletter then use html tables old layout

Comment: @dippas i cannot use class and id, because it is a design for letter, to be send on mailboxes, like mail.com,mail.ru,gmail.com. They strip all classes.

Comment: I deleted my 1st comment regarding that as soon I saw it was a newsletter, see my other comment

Comment: @dippas i tried with table and ran into similar issue https://jsfiddle.net/cvc5f6rp/

Comment: @dippas i ended up with that block with image, always stick to the bottom of the table, and it cannot be moved using margin or padding

Answer (score 1):

My Idea is something like the following:

```
<table style="border-collapse:collapse; margin-left: 16px; margin-bottom: -16px; padding-top: 16px; width:180px; min-height:120px; ">

    <tbody><tr style="outline: 1px solid #e5e5e5; height: 85px; text-align: center;">
        <td>

        </td>
<td>
  <table>
    <tbody><tr style="height: 30px;"></tr>
    <tr>

    </tr><img style="width: 40px; height: 40px;" src="http://www.iconsplace.com/icons/preview/salmon/pig-256.png">
 </tbody></table></td>

    </tr>

    <tr style="background-color: #f5f5f5; border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5; border-left: 1px solid #e5e5e5;">
        <td>
            <table style="min-height: 34px; display:inline-table;">
                <tbody><tr>
            <td style="height: 34px; width: 35px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; line-height: 40px;">
                <img style="width: 16px; height: 16px; border: none;" src="http://araskie.xtgem.com/file/images/16x16/Dollar.png" title="Currency">
            </td>
            <td style="font-size: 12px; color: #777; font-weight: bold; line-height: 1.2em; margin-top: 9px; margin-right: 30px; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap; word-wrap: normal;">
                <span style="font-family: arial,sans-serif;">some text</span>
            </td>




                <td style="right:0;bottom:0;">

                        <img src="http://s017.radikal.ru/i407/1605/de/a777fd1811b5.png">
            </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody></table>

        </td>




    </tr>


</tbody></table>
```

Comment: ended up with that https://jsfiddle.net/cvc5f6rp/8/  But still there is a little space to the right of <img src="http://s017.radikal.ru/i407/1605/de/a777fd1811b5.png">   and to the bottom. can't fit it in there

Comment: As others have mentioned here, you're going to have to make your email out of nested tables. This answer really is the best if you're wanting to make the email bullet-proof in all email clients.

Comment: @AaronLavers well.. i would accept it but the thing is, you cannot place things on top of eachother still, using this method.

Comment: @marshal1834 in that instance then, I'd be cutting up the graphics in such a way that you don't have to overlay anything.

Answer (score 0):

Use `right:0;bottom:0;` for image div

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need the following.

```
<img style="width: 32px;height: 32px;position: absolute;bottom: 0;right: 0;" src="http://www.iconsplace.com/icons/preview/salmon/pig-256.png">
```

I am not sure if I understand the problem, but check the answer if it is not that you need please let me know an I can try to help

**UPDATE**
yes that's true now I understand the problem, I had some time ago a lot of problems making some newsletter. the only way to do that was make that into tables, that means that you need create the table and make the rows for simulate that position. Some links that can help

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2005/08/optimizing-css-presentation-in-html-emails/

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2007/07/tables-in-html-emails-nesting/

Comment: Cannot use absolute positionning, it will get stripped by the mail services.

Comment: i ended with with something like this https://jsfiddle.net/cvc5f6rp/4/   i got a first table, and then another table inside which is inline table, but i still need to move an image in a last td with margin

Comment: I think that margin not work in some emails. I think that the best could be make a td empty with a width for move the image to the right, in the other td you need a table with 2 rows, the first row with the height for move the image to the bottom